# Updating Ini file - Issue with the store function

Tags: ini

I am trying to modify a value of the dbVersion property for this ini file

```
[Settings]
Access=ReadWrite
Type=1
AutomationDbString=jdbc:mysql:ser=php&password=php
automationServerTestResultPath=/testresult/
automationServerTestResultPathWrite=testresult
automationServerTestResultPathRead=http:testresult
automationServerBuildPath=\testresult\\builds
automationServerReferenceFilesPath=\\reference_files
automationToolBaseUrl=http:/dpa
agentInstallBuildFolder = c:\\dev\\builds
agentAntLogFolder = c:\\dev\\logs
exportToTaf=true
dbEnable=true
dbVersion=606A8
dbName=archauto606
archticsLocation=//source/QA
userName=Administator
pwdName=hombre007!
archticsPatchLocation=patch\

[Root]
```

After executing this part of code the structure of my file has changed

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\agent\\Testcomplete2.ini"));
System.out.println("dbVersion = " + p.getProperty("dbVersion"));
p.setProperty("dbVersion", "606A21");
p.store(new FileOutputStream("C:\\agent\\Testcomplete2.ini"), null);



 #Mon Jul 22 13:49:54 EDT 2013
[Root]=
agentInstallBuildFolder=c\:\\dev\\builds
AutomationDbString=jdbc\:mysql\:ser\=php&password\=php
automationServerBuildPath=\testresult\\builds
automationServerTestResultPathWrite=testresult
dbVersion=606A21
pwdName=hombre007\!
exportToTaf=true
Type=1
userName=Administator
automationServerTestResultPathRead=http\:testresult
dbEnable=true
archticsPatchLocation=patch
[Settings]=
automationServerReferenceFilesPath=\\reference_files
Access=ReadWrite
automationToolBaseUrl=http\:/dpa
archticsLocation=//source/QA
automationServerTestResultPath=/testresult/
dbName=archauto606
agentAntLogFolder=c\:\\dev\\logs
```

However after executiong the line p.store , I noticed that the structure of my file has changed and i was not able to parse propelry the file . Just asking if is there a way to modify only the value without changing the structure of the file .

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that `Properties.load()` and `Properties.store()` do not necessarily guarantee the order in which entries (or even sections) are stored - possibly because the data structure used internally to store the results of `load()` might be a hash table or something similar. If that is the case, and your parsing breaks as a result, you'll have to either a) fix your parsing code to not rely on things being in a specific order or b) write your own code to do the replacement that doesn't rely on the `load()`/`store()` methods...

Comment: I found an eclipse library named InitEditor and that fixed my issue . Thanks .